# Oracle Dynamic Stored procedure - While concatenating string with parameter ,parameter value changing to inverted question mark(“¿”)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures, dynamic-programming

Parameter declaration: `P_NAME VARCHAR2,`

parameter value is Arabic ( كمار ) and it want to concatenate with some string.
While Concatenating string with parameter ,parameter value changing to inverted question mark(“¿”)

Variable declared : `SQLQUERY VARCHAR2 (4000);`

```
SQLQUERY  := SQLQUERY  || ' AND (a.MRNO=UPPER(''' || p_NAME || ''') OR UPPER(a.FULL_NAME) like ''' || UPPER(p_NAME) || '%'' OR a.ARABIC_FULL_NAME like ''%' || to_char(p_NAME) || '%'')';
```

Created a temporary table and inserted Parameter(p_NAME); value getting correct and inserted properly.

after that same parameter concatenated , that time only issue existing.

```
AND (a.MRNO=UPPER('¿¿¿¿¿¿¿') OR UPPER(a.FULL_NAME) like '¿¿¿¿¿¿¿%' OR a.ARABIC_FULL_NAME like '%¿¿¿¿¿¿¿%')
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you add your line of code where getting issue? Can you also add some sample data and expected output if any? and what is the current characterset of database?

Comment: Question edited

Comment: It would be useful if you post a[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example]/https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also you should post the characterset of the server and describe which client you use and its NLS settings. I think the inverted question mark is used to display characters that are unknown to the client. But please post the MCV example.

Comment: @miracle173 : Issue is not with NLS setting.. what i understood that while concatenating some mismatch happening otherwise insertion also same issue will occur

Answer (score 0):

Added to_char

```
 SQLQUERY  := SQLQUERY  || ' AND (a.MRNO=UPPER(''' || p_NAME || ''') OR  UPPER(a.FULL_NAME) like ''%' || UPPER(p_NAME) || '%'' OR To_char(a.ARABIC_FULL_NAME) like ''%' || to_char(p_NAME) || '%'')';
```